# How to select text and then perform a cypress test on it?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a small application to test on cypress. It has a editor for user to add description and stuff. The user can make the text bold, italic etc. The user can also remove the formatting added so far on the text. But to remove the formatting the text should be selected like we normally do in any word editor.

My question is how can I test this feature while keeping the text selected.

A simple code example would be as follows:

`<p>This is the description text</p>`

So far I have got this but this does not keep the text selected of course, any idea how to cater this?

```
            cy.get('p').contains('This is the description text');
            cy.get('.remove-formats').click();
            cy.get('.tools')
             .within(() => cy.get('button').should('not.have.class', 'is-active'));
```

What change should I make in the first line that the text stays selected when the second line executes as I want the remove formats to be performed on the text only. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

The text editor is very simple just like the one we have for stackoverflow.
[image]

Similar to how we need to select the text first and then click bold to get the text bold, otherwise it does not imply to the text. How would I structure cypress tests for this?
I have selected the text through dblclick() but as soon as I click on any option to test that feature the text does not stay selected in cypress tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double click to select the text.

```js
cy.contains('This is the description text').dblclick()
```

You can also use a combination of `ctrl+A`

```js
cy.contains('This is the description text').click().type('{ctrl+a}')
```

Comment: This selects the text but as soon as the next line is executed, it does not keeps the text selected. I want to execute the second line while making sure the text stays s selected

Comment: Can there be a then block that I can use it with maybe?

Comment: What is the next step that you are doing after the text select?

Comment: Clear all formatting on the text selected. To do that I need to click on another button while keeping the text selected

Comment: Is your webpage public? Or do you have any similar text editor on the internet, that I can look into? Because it is difficult to debug based on the available information.

Comment: I have updated the question adding further details, can you please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 .type("{selectall}{leftarrow}")
```

from cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments) `{selectall}` - Selects all text by creating a selection range

Comment: No luck, it selects the text but as soon as it goes to the second line the text is no longer selected. I am wondering if this Is this default cypress behaviour?

Comment: ok, but what happens if you will not use `.click()` and do your formatting instead? Or it `goes to the second line` anyway? just want to clarify, thanks

Comment: It goes to second line anyway. If I remove the click, it will just get the element with the mentioned class. But in this case also it will not keep the previous text selected.